# leaking memory and possible malloc error

Tags: c

I am building an array and I want it to be a fixed size so that as I read in a file it only stores the last 10 commands. The file seems to read in correctly and it looks right when I print it but for some reason my memory is not getting freed. 
MAX is set to 1000 
and historySize is read earlier from the user. I ran valgrind on my code and when the calls to these functions are commented out I do not have any leaks.

I have a char ** history under my #includes

Here is my code

```
void setupHistoryFile()
{
    char string[MAX];
    FILE *fp;
    int len;
    int pos = 0;
    fp = fopen(".ush_history","r");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        //create the file
        fp = fopen(".ush_history","w");
    }
    else
    {
        history = (char**)malloc(historySize * sizeof(char*));//setup history file
        fgets(string,MAX,fp);
        len = strlen(string);
        if(string[len-1]=='\n')
            string[len-1]='\0';
        while(!feof(fp))
        {
            if(history[pos] != NULL)
            {
                free(history[pos]);
                history[pos]=NULL;
            }
            history[pos] = (char*)malloc((strlen(string)+1) * sizeof(char));
            //printf("Should be copying %s\n",string);          
            strcpy(history[pos], string);           
            pos++;
            pos = pos % historySize;
            fgets(string,MAX,fp);
            len = strlen(string);
            if(string[len-1]=='\n')
                string[len-1]='\0';
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I do have a function that cleans the history and it looks like this

```
void cleanHistory()
{
    int i;
    if(history != NULL)
    {
        for(i=0;i<historySize;i++)
        {
            free(history[i]);
            history[i] = NULL;
        }
        free(history);
        history = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your deallocation function `cleanHistory()` is getting called on the very same pointer array to which you allocated the memory? You can put breakpoints in `cleanHistory()` and check if this functions gets called at all.

Comment: I have a char** history under my #includes and I am able to print the contents of it in main after calling the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you allocate memory with `malloc`, the chunk of memory allocated is not initialized. That means that if you do something like `history[pos] != NULL` might actually be true even if you haven't put anything there.

To be certain that the allocated memory is initialized, either use `calloc` or `memset`.

**Edit**
To be more specific, this part of your code will behave badly:

```
if(history[pos] != NULL)
{
    free(history[pos]);
    history[pos]=NULL;
}
```

If you are not lucky, `history[pos]` will contain some old data, which means you will try to `free` something you have not allocated.

As a small side-note, you should be looping while `fgets` doesn't return `NULL`. As it is now you don't check for errors from `fgets`. Something like this:

```
while (fgets(...) != NULL)
```

Then you don't need the double calls to `fgets`, and you will stop looping on both error and end of file.

Comment: Don't use `calloc` or `memset` to initialize an array of pointers. Use a loop and set each array element to NULL. The binary representation of NULL may be all bits 0 on most systems, but this is not required.

Comment: @Secure While technically true, do you know of any modern and commonly used computer (outside old mainframes) where NULL is not the same as 0?

Comment: It is usually a choice of the compiler implementation, not of the machine. I had an old x86 compiler years ago that used all bits 1 for NULL pointers. So in theory, the gcc developers could decide to use it in the next version. Or to use a different NULL representation for each coming version. It would be slightly crazy, but still conforming. However, when confronted with the choice to either save some minor typing or to stay fully portable, I usually prefer the latter.

Answer (score 0):

You allocate memory for history, but you don't initialize it. That means at first pas through history, it might happen that history[pos] is not allocated, nor NULL, and you'll try to deallocate unallocated memory.